# specify project id for google app engine project

Tags: google-app-engine

When creating a new project from the Google Developers Console, it asks for a project name.  If an id equivalent to that project name is available, it makes the id to be the same as the project name.  If not, some unique id is system generated.

When an id is not available, is there a way to determine who owns the id? There's an id I would like to use, and I'm not sure who is using it (or whether I mistakenly used it in a different GAE project).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created the id (and you didn't delete it) you should see it in the [Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/). If you deleted it [you can't re-use it anymore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/uploading):

> Accept the generated project ID or supply your own ID. This project ID
>   is used as the App Engine application ID. Note that this ID can only
>   be used once: if you subsequently delete your project, you won't be
>   able to re-use the ID in a new project.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way to know this. You can visit the appspot version of the website (appid.appspot.com) and maybe gather something from there, but there is no way to know who is using it.